# Excel If formula with OR, avoiding #N/A

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Currently facing a problem, long story short:
I'm trying to combine 2 formulas into one, by making use of the OR-function, but if one of the 2 conditions does not exist, it gives me an #N/A back.
There's 3 conditions that can happen: "MTI", "MTI Z" and "MTO". What I would like is that the formula searches for any combination in column L with either "MTI" or "MTI Z" (might also be both) and if that combination exists, give back a 1. If not (so only MTO exists) then return a 0 (in this case it will be an #N/A, but I can fix that with either ISNA or IFERROR).

Formula 1 is:

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI")=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI"),L:L,0),0),1,0)
```

Formula 2 is

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI Z")=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI Z"),L:L,0),0),1,0)
```

Both formulas work, giving back a "1" when there is respectively a "MTI" or "MTI Z"

However, when I try to combine them, if 1 of the 2 does not exist in the list, it gives me an #N/A, even though I'm using OR (which would state if at least 1 of the 2 exists, go ahead).

```
=IF(OR(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI Z")=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI Z"),L:L,0),0)
,CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI")=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI"),L:L,0),0)),1,0)
```

How can I adjust my formula so that it does work?

Comment: Could you provide a few example cells and what the returned value should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit more straight forward:

```
=SIGN(COUNTIF(L:L,CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI*")))
```

Comment: You sir, are a genious :)! Thank you very much! One question though, the formula "sign" is not very well known by me. The formula "countif" does look in column L:L to see whether there is the combination with either MTI or MTI Z (therefore the MTI*), then counts it if this is the case. 
Sign just makes sure it is either 1,0 or -1 and does not add the total count together?

Comment: @Thijsk, happy to help! Exactly right, the sign just returns 1 if the count is positive, 0 if 0 and -1 if negative.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each of these formulas in an `IFERROR([formula],0)`

Comment: This would not resolve the issue that it would only go to iferror if there is just MTO.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding two IFERROR 'wrappers' so you return FALSE when no match, not #N/A.

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI Z")=INDEX(L:L, MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2, "MTI Z"), L:L, 0)), FALSE),
       IFERROR(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI")=INDEX(L:L, MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI"), L:L, 0)), FALSE)),
 1, 0)
```

Comment: The problem is that it should only give me an #N/A when it is MTO. Now it is still considering either MTI or MTI Z as an error if one of the two does not exist in the combination. Thanks for your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your formula as

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI"),L:L,0)),
       ISNUMBER(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,"MTI Z"),L:L,0))),1,0)
```